# How do I prove $2$ is prime (or irreducible) in all $Z[\sqrt{d}]$ with $d < -7$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

> How do I prove $2$ is prime (or irreducible) in all $Z[\sqrt{d}]$ with $d < -7$?

I feel like the answer is right under my nose, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Do you know about the norm on $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$? (And it must be "irreducible", $2$ is prime only if $d\equiv 5 \pmod{8}$.)

Comment: The norm? I saw that in the book somewhere... And how do you make that nice Z?

Comment: `\mathbb{Z}`. What do you remember about the norm?

Comment: Let $d\ne 1$ be square-free. The integers in $Q(\sqrt{d})$ has either shape $\gamma=a+b\sqrt{d}$, where $a$ and $b$ are integers, except that in the case $d\equiv -1\pmod{4}$, $\gamma=(1/2)(a+b\sqrt{d})$, where $a$ and $b$ are odd integers, is allowed. If $d$ is negative and less than $-7$, and $b\ne 0$, then $a^2+|d|b^2$ and $(1/4)(a^2+|d|b^2)\gt 2$. So the norm of $\gamma$ is greater than $2$.

Comment: My understanding is that elements can only be prime and irreducible in a UFD, otherwise they are irreducible but not prime. And there is no unique factorization for $d < -163$, so then 2 can be irreducible but not prime in those.

Answer (score 3):

For convenience, let's say $-d$ instead of $d$, with $d \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mu(d) \neq 0$.

If 2 is composite or reducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-d}]$, that means $x^2 + dy^2 = 2$ has a solution in integers, or, if $d \equiv 3 \mod 4$, the equation $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{dy^2}{4} = 2$ holds. For the former, the only solutions are $1^2 + 1 \times 1^2$ and $0^2 + 2 \times 1^2$. And for the latter, $\frac{1^2}{4} + \frac{7 \times 1^2}{4}$. These solutions correspond to the factorizations $(1 - i)(1 + i)$, $(-1)(\sqrt{-2})^2$ and $\left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{-7}}{2}\right)$.

If $d > 9$ and $y \neq 0$, then clearly $x^2 + dy^2 \geq 10 > 2$ or $\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{dy^2}{4} \geq \frac{5}{2} > 2$.